# ActiveModelSerializer, how do I get more info the JSON API response about the association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, json-api

I am using Rails 5 and AMS 10. My questions are in bold.

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0.rc1'

rails -v
Rails 5.0.0.beta3
```

I am using the JSON API specifications. I have this in an config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb file:

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json_api
```

**Is the point of this to apply convention to JSON API responses which have total freedom in customization of the nodes? This leads to faster understanding of the data from developers who consume the API for like front-end Ember apps or mobile native apps?**

This is my RentalUnitSerializer:

```
class RentalUnitSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :rooms, :bathrooms, :price, :price_cents

  belongs_to :user
end
```

This is my UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email

  def name
    names = object.name.split(" ")
    "#{names[0].first}. #{names[1]}"
  end
end
```

This is my rental_units_controller:

```
class RentalUnitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_rental_unit, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /rental_units
  def index
    @rental_units = RentalUnit.all

    render json: @rental_units
  end
```

This is my JSON response when I hit the /rental_units endpoint.

```
{
"data": [{
            "id": "1",
            "type": "rental_units",
            "attributes": {
                "rooms": 2,
                "bathrooms": 2,
                "price": null,
                "price_cents": 50000
            },
            "relationships": {
                "user": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "1",
                        "type": "users"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "rental_units",
            "attributes": {
                "rooms": 2,
                "bathrooms": 2,
                "price": null,
                "price_cents": 50000
            },
            "relationships": {
                "user": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "1",
                        "type": "users"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

**How do I get the user's name in the relationships section of the JSON API response?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.includes(:user)` to your query on the first line of your `index` method in RentalUnitsController, thusly:

```
@rental_units = RentalUnit.includes(:user).all
```

That will add the actual data from the `:user` relationship's target object to your RentalUnit object and to the serialized JSON.